# linq2sql best way to update POCO having many columns

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I am trying to update a POCO using lin2sql. I can also use entity framework.  For updating objects I follow the next routine.

```
//GridView Control gives me some updated POCOS As an Example: Person updated;

 function UpdatePerson(Person myUpdatedPersonfromUI)
  {
   using (Entity con = new Entity() ) {
     var recordFromdB = from obj in con.Person where obj.PK = myUpdatedPersonfromUI.PK 
            select obj;
      Person personOnDB = recordFromdB.Single();


        // now for each column I update personOnDB

            personOnDB.Property1 =   myUpdatedPersonfromUI.Property1 ;    
            personOnDB.Property2 =   myUpdatedPersonfromUI.Property2 ;  
            personOnDB.Property3 =   myUpdatedPersonfromUI.Property3 ;  
            personOnDB.Property4 =   myUpdatedPersonfromUI.Property4 ;  
       // continue updating fields              ...
                  ..
                  .                             
            personOnDB.Property124 =   myUpdatedPersonfromUI.Property124 ;  


             con.SaveChanges();



    }
  }
```

Do I have to update each property manually . Please help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an object mapping tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) which pretty much will do the work for you - in this simple case (property names match between source and target) it would be a one-liner to map these.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using you same object type in the UI, why not just plug it into the DAL and call update directly?

[This link](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Oct/01/Complex-Detached-Entities-in-LINQ-to-SQL-more-Nightmares) gives details on how to do it.

Comment: Actually, what you said is what I want.  But It will create new record  instead of Updating existing record. I miss some point

Comment: I checked the link but this is not a solution to my question. Thank you @cjk.